# How do you access the column values of all rows after selecting them?

Tags: php

I have the following code set up and mysql_num_rows echos 2 as it should be.
I would like to somehow access the second row which has been selected but can't figure out how. echo $lTitl always returns the title from the first row in the random order, but i would also like to access rows after that. how do i do this?

```
$sql = "SELECT id, seller, title, kondition, price, shippingcost FROM items WHERE active='1' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 2";
$item_query = mysql_query($sql, $connect);

foreach ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($item_query) as $test) {
    $id = $row["id"];
    $seller = $row["seller"];
    $lTitl = $row["title"];
    $lCond = $row["kondition"];
    //$lPrimIma = $row["primaryimage"];   
    $lPric = $row["price"];
    $lShip = $row["shippingcost"];
}
echo $lTitl;
```

Comment: mysql_fetch_assoc() only returns one row, so your foreach(mysql_fetch_assoc() as $test) will only loop once. You want mysql_fetch_all

Comment: see my answer @willi http://stackoverflow.com/a/21056095/1607528

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this by storing values in array when looping
You need to use `mysql_fetch_all` for retrieving more than one column.
**Note that mysql functions are deprecated. Use `mysqli or PDO instead`.**

```
foreach ($row = mysql_fetch_all($item_query) as $test) {
$id[] = $row["id"];
$seller[] = $row["seller"];
$lTitl[] = $row["title"];
$lCond[] = $row["kondition"];
//$lPrimIma = $row["primaryimage"];   
$lPric[] = $row["price"];
$lShip[] = $row["shippingcost"];
}
echo $lTitl[0]; // will print first row
echo $lTitl[1]; // will print second row
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$one = mysql_fetch_assoc($item_query);
$second = mysql_fetch_assoc($item_query);

echo  $one["title"]; // first title
echo  $second["title"]; // second title

**EDIT**
$titles = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($item_query)) {
   $title[]  = $row['title'];
}

foreach($titles as $title){
   echo $title;
}
```

Comment: Hope the result set only ends up with two items! Progress the OP's skills by showing re-usable, dynamic code.

Comment: @Rottingham  I know. See `LIMIT 2`. He needs only two rows. No loops. For why?

Comment: So when he removes `LIMIT 2` and wants the third, then what? Add another $third = ... and $fourth = ...

Comment: @Rottingham hmmm. If he will want use `mysql_fetch_row`? Or use `Doctrine`? In common:  @willi asked specific question - I said specific the answer.

Comment: @Muhammet i didn`t understand U.

Comment: @voodoo417 Not to argue mate, but the question says, "echo $lTitl always returns the title from the first row in the random order, but i would also like to access rows after that. how do i do this?". You inferred from some bad code he would only ever want 2.

Comment: @voodoo417, `fetch all` approach will be more helpful, even if he has two rows

Answer (score 0):

Switch to fetch_all

```
foreach (mysql_fetch_all($item_query) as $row) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    // Do all the stuff you want to do here
}
```

And for the love of Programming, stop using mysql_ functions! See the big red box here:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 0):

The result saved into `$test`. You have to change into this:

```
while ($test = mysql_fetch_assoc($item_query)) {
    $id = $test["id"];
    $seller = $test["seller"];
    $lTitl = $test["title"];
    $lCond = $test["kondition"];
    //$lPrimIma = $test["primaryimage"];   
    $lPric = $test["price"];
    $lShip = $test["shippingcost"];
}
```